# In Excel, how to get the highest value's name?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Why does this not work?

screenshot of issue:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

On my system, it works.

Maybe your list separator is not comma. Check your regional settings, mine look like this: [image: my regional settings]

If you have a different list separator (like semicolon), use it in the formula (instead of the comma), like this:

```
=INDEX(B3:B28;MATCH(MAX(D3:D28);D3:D28;0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to **File- Options- Advanced** and check the **Use system separators** settings:

[image]

If you check the **option**, go to **Control Panel**- **Region** and check the system settings:

[image]

Comment: your answer doesn't really provide extra information compared to already existing answer